# multiple variable assignment in one line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know normal practise to do multiple variable assignment in python is:

```
a, b, c = {}, {}, 0
```

However, can I do multiple variable assignment in one line, separating by semicolon? Should there be any problem ?

```
a={}; b={}; c=0
```

Comment: Sure, why not? Have you tried it out on your Python shell/IDLE? :-)

Comment: You can use semicolon to separate any kind of statement. There's nothing special about variable assignment.

Comment: hi @Barmar, I already tried in IDE pycharm. It works so far. But there is warning issued by Pycharm. The warning is 'PEP 8: multiple statement in one line (semicolon)'.  I read somewhere PEP 8 is python style guide

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a _styling guide_, offering guidance for best-practices in formatting Python code. The semi-colons _are technically valid_ and your code will run. But if PEP 8 discourages it, then it's best to avoid it (even though it works). There may be some situations where meh, semicolons are convenient and useful for one-liners. But it's up to you, really.

Comment: You'll get that same warning when you use semicolons with any statements, not just assignments. E.g. `print 1; print 2`

Comment: It is against the PEP8 style guide. Whether or not that should stop you is up to you

Comment: HI @ juanpa.arrivillaga, that means the code still work rite, it just not a normal practise

Comment: Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.